# Simulate ReflectionTypeLoadException being thrown during domain types collection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly, appdomain

I'm able to collect all the types from the current domain calling this:

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    .ToList();
```

Assume no exception is thrown. Nevertheless I'd like to simulate `ReflectionTypeLoadException` to be thrown during that process.

How to corrupt any existing type in my code for this exception to occur?

Alternatively, if above cannot be achieved, how can I dynamically create an artificial assembly with some corrupted type to infect the domain (current or new)? In particular I'm looking for some clues regarding the implementation of the `Infect()` method below:

```
Infect(AppDomain.CurrentDomain); // inject corrupted type
try
{
    var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
        .ToList();
}
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
{
    // done
}
```

Comment: Is that for unit test purposes?

Answer (score 2):

This is for unit test purposes like you say by answered to my question in comments.

So why not move the logic that get all types in your current AppDomain assemblies to a class that implement a interface like the code below:

```
public interface ITypeProvider
{
    ICollection<Type> GetTypes();
}

public class AppDomainTypeProvider : ITypeProvider
{
    public ICollection<Type> GetTypes()
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .ToList();
    }
}

public class MyAwesomeClassThatUseMyTypeProvider
{
    private readonly ITypeProvider _typeProvider;

    public MyAwesomeClassThatUseMyTypeProvider(ITypeProvider typeProvider)
    {
        _typeProvider = typeProvider;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var types = _typeProvider.GetTypes();
    }
}
```

Use this interface in your code where the logic is called.

Then to simulate the exception `ReflectionTypeLoadException` for your unit tests just use Moq or any equivalent for that like I do below (i'm using Nunit for Assertions):

```
var typeProviderMoq = new Mock<ITypeProvider>();
typeProviderMoq.Setup(p => p.GetTypes()).Throws(new ReflectionTypeLoadException(new [] { typeof(string)}, new[] { new Exception("test purpose") }));
var myAwesomeClass = new MyAwesomeClassThatUseMyTypeProvider(typeProviderMoq.Object);

Assert.Throws<ReflectionTypeLoadException>(() => myAwesomeClass.DoSomething());
```

Comment: Thank you (+1), I appreciate your solution which is very correct, and I'll most likely switch to this approach, nevertheless I'd still like to know if the trick I've asked about is possible.